# Running TypeScript Mocha with module es6

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, typescript, mocha.js

I wanted to set up some mocha tests for the TypeScript App of my Rails application. I added one single stupid test to get started. But I keep getting this error:

```
/home/bernhard/Programs/ruby/cube_trainer/jstests/utils/optional.spec.ts:1
import { some, none, mapOptional, forceValue, hasValue, checkNone } from '../../app/javascript/cube_trainer/app/utils/optional';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
...stacktrace...
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I realized by trial and error that the line `"module": "es6"` in tsconfig.json seems to be causing this. If I change it to `"module": "commonjs"`, my test runs and passes. However, my rails app stops working if I do that.

I consider this problem solved if I achieve any of the following:
 * Make my Rails app work with the `"module": "commonjs"` option.
 * Make my tests work with the `"module": "es6"`
 * I manage to use a different tsconfig for mocha (but I would only consider this option if I could include the existing tsconfig and change just that one option rather than copying the entire file)

Btw, I don't have a deep understanding of all these config options, I just copy pasted stuff together until it worked. So if anything in my configs is stupid, feel free to point it out. The only thing that I did intentionally is that I made TypeScript as strict as possible as long as I could do this without breaking things that are outside of my control.

## Important files for reference

The full repo is here: https://github.com/Lykos/cube_trainer
The README contains installation instructions (if you have postgresql, yarn and ruby already setup, it should be simple)

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "*": ["node_modules/*", "app/javascript/*"]
    },
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "removeComments": false,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "node_modules",
    "vendor",
    "public"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Note that my tsconfig orininated from the one that Rails provides. See here:

https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/lib/install/examples/typescript/tsconfig.json

I changed `"lib": ["es6", "dom"],` to `"lib": ["dom", "es2017"],` to fix a problem, I changed the target to `es6` and I added some more options to make TypeScript stricter.

I don't know whether those options make sense in general, but I had a hard time trying to make my app work with Rails and TS and without those options.

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "cube_trainer",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.0",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.0.1",
    "@rxweb/reactive-form-validators": "^1.9.9-beta4",
    "angular-new-router": "angular/router",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "http-methods-enum": "^0.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "rails-ujs": "^5.2.4-2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "snake-case-typescript": "^0.0.2",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "author": "Bernhard F. Brodowsky",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/Lykos/cube_trainer.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register jstests/**/*.spec.ts"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.11",
    "@types/mocha": "^7.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.31",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^7.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want someone to debug the app for you, you need to add more information on how to start your app and what is expected to do. Your js/ts configuration a bit of a mess and contains a lot of meaningless stuff, which makes suggesting the cleanest solution without running the app not-so-easy. However, I can add that it is a common thing to have separate configs for tests and the app. The config inheritance exists (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#configuration-inheritance-with-extends.

Comment: You can check an example of separate configs here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: Hello, wow, I didn't expect anyone would actually go through the trouble of trying to install and debug my app for me. I was more hoping/expecting that I am doing something insanely stupid that people can see just from my configs. In any case, I added a README.md to my app and linked it in my question. I also added an explanation where my tsconfig comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Basically I needed to replace `"module": "es6"` by `"module": "commonjs"` in the `tsconfig.json`. Given that this caused other problems, I needed a smart solution. One possibility would be to use multiple TS configs. In the end, I decided to just override it via environment variable in the script that runs it. Like this:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "test": "TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{\"module\":\"commonjs\"}' mocha -r ts-node/register jstests/**/*.spec.ts"
  },
```